# VBScript - Pass argument to HTA

Tags: variables, vbscript, hta

I am working on some scripting in VBScript, I need to pass some variable values along to a HTA I am going to use as a front end to show an update is taking place.

How would I do that?

```
VBScript-------

TestVar1 = "Something 1"
TestVar2 = "Something 2"

wshShell.Run "Updater.hta " & TestVar1 & TestVar2
```

Then

```
HTA------- 

TestVar1 = Something.Arguments(0)
TestVar2 = Something.Arguments(1)

Msgbox TestVar1
Msgbox TestVar2
```

I realise thats not exactly correct code, I am just placing it to illustrate what I am attempting to do.

Any help you guys can provide in solving this would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enclose your parameters in quotes. Since VBScript uses `"` for string literals, you need to escape it by doubling it `""` or you can use the `Chr()` function to specify the quote character:

```
TestVar1 = "Something 1"
TestVar2 = "Something 2"

Dim strParams
strParams = strParams & " " & Chr(34) & TestVar1 & Chr(34)
strParams = strParams & " " & Chr(34) & TestVar2 & Chr(34)

wshShell.Run "updater.hta" & strParams
```

In your HTA, the `Arguments` collection is not available. Instead, you have to parse the `CommandLine` property of the HTA object. In this case, the `CommandLine` received by your HTA would look like the following:

```
"updater.hta" "Something 1" "Something 2"
```

So you have two options to retrieve your arguments. You can use a regex to grab everything within quotes, or you can `Split()` the `CommandLine` on quotes. If you have quotes *within* one of your parameters, things get trickier and you may want to consider using a different character for enclosing your parameters.

Here's a skeleton HTA that uses `Split()` to extract the arguments:

```
<head>
    <HTA:APPLICATION
        ID="myhta" 
        APPLICATIONNAME="HTA Test"
    >
</head>

<script language="VBScript">
    Sub Window_OnLoad()
        a = Split(myhta.CommandLine, Chr(34))
        MsgBox "Arg 1 = " & a(3)
        MsgBox "Arg 2 = " & a(5)
    End Sub
</script>
```

When you use `Split()`, you'll get something like the following:

```
a = Split(myhta.CommandLine, Chr(34))
' a(0) = <blank>
' a(1) = "updater.hta"
' a(2) = " "
' a(3) = "Something 1"
' a(4) = " "
' a(5) = "Something 2"
' a(6) = <blank>
```

So `a(3)` becomes your first argument and `a(5)` becomes your second.

If you want to use a regex, it becomes:

```
Sub Window_OnLoad()

    With New RegExp
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = """([^""]+)"""
        Set c = .Execute(myhta.CommandLine)
    End With

    For i = 1 To c.Count - 1        ' Skip i = 0 (the HTA filename)
        MsgBox "Arg " & i & " = " & c(i).SubMatches(0)
    Next

End Sub
```

This would display:

```
Arg 1 = Something 1
Arg 2 = Something 2
```

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but I'm trying to learn this stuff from the Internet hehe. Can you edit your very helpful response into what would be in the VBS and in the HTA to facilitate the bridge using the regex example? Thank you.

The main thing I am passing to the updater from the VBS file is the scripts location, I am creating a portable wrapper for some programs, and I am passing control over to the HTA to perform some file operations (replacing the platform if needed) . So I shouldn't be passing anything with quotes, just file paths and names etc.

Comment: The first code block is the VBS file. That simply sets up the call to the HTA and passes the params. The rest pertains to the HTA. I've shown a skeleton HTA just so that you can see how the ID (`ID="myhta"`) is used later on to query the `CommandLine` property. The HTA's `Window_OnLoad()` event is where you'll grab the passed arguments. In that same HTA skeleton, I'm showing how you can `Split()` the `CommandLine` property (option 1). At the end of the answer, I'm showing an alternate `Window_OnLoad()` event that uses a regex instead of `Split()` (option 2).

Comment: You can use """" instead of chr(34) - it is a lot easier and faster to type

Comment: @cup - You can. I actually use that in the regex pattern above. Easier to type but also more prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is post is a little old, but it helped me find my solution for Macro Express Pro.

Our users have to gather data from other applications (such as IBM Personal Communications, or PCOMM, emulators) before we call the HTA. We then use "Program Launch" to call the HTA and pass the data as parameters:

`Program Launch: "Group Record.hta" (Normal)`

`Parameters: "%Variable1%" "%Variable2%"`

To handle the HTA receiving this data from Macro Express Pro, I've developed the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9" />
    <title>Group Record Display</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION
      ID="myhta"
      APPLICATIONNAME = "Group Record Display"
    />
  </head>

  <script language="VBScript">
    Sub Main()
      strArg = Split(myhta.CommandLine, chr(34))
      
      For i = 3 to (UBound(strArg) - 1)
        If strArgLine = "" Then
          strArgLine = strArg(i)
        Else
          strArgLine = strArgLine & "," & strArg(i)
          If i = UBound(strArg) Then
            Exit For
          End If
        End If
      Next

      Var1 = strArg(3) 'Whatever was passed to this index
      Window_Title = Split(strArg(5), " ") 'PCOMM session "Session A - [24 x 80]"

      For j = 0 to 3
        If Len(Window_Title(j)) = 1 Then
          strSession = Window_Title(j) 'Session letter "A"
          Exit For
        End If
      Next

      document.getElementById("MainDisplay").InnerHTML = Var1
    End Sub
  </script>

  <body onLoad=Main()>
    <div id="MainDisplay"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```